# javafx how to get selected row data in table view with checkbox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

In this project I can't get whether the Checkbox data was selected or not in the console output.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableWithCheckbox extends Application {
   final TableView<Player> table = new TableView<Player>();
    ObservableList<Player> data ;
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    table.setItems(createData());
    final TableColumn<Player, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    final TableColumn<Player, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    final TableColumn<Player, Boolean> injuredColumn = new TableColumn<>("Injured");
    firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>("firstName"));
    lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>("lastName"));
    injuredColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, Boolean>("injured"));
    final Callback<TableColumn<Player, Boolean>, TableCell<Player, Boolean>> cellFactory = CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(injuredColumn);
    injuredColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Player, Boolean>, TableCell<Player, Boolean>>() {
      @Override
      public TableCell<Player, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Player, Boolean> column) {
        TableCell<Player, Boolean> cell = cellFactory.call(column);
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return cell ;
      }
    });
    injuredColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    injuredColumn.setEditable(true);

    // This appears not to get invoked:
    injuredColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Player,Boolean>>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(CellEditEvent<Player, Boolean> event) {
        System.out.println("Edit commit");
      }
    });

    table.setEditable(true);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn, injuredColumn);

    root.setCenter(table);

    Button button = new Button("Dump info");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        for (Player p : table.getItems()) {
          System.out.println(p);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }); Button button1 = new Button("add");
    button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
  data.add(new Player("hbghj", "hjhbbccc77", true));
      }
    });
    root.setBottom(button); 
    root.setTop(button1);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 600));
    primaryStage.show();    
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  private ObservableList<Player> createData() {
    List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(
        new Player("Hugo" ,"Lloris", false),
        new Player("Brad", "Friedel", false),
        new Player("Kyle", "Naughton", false),
        new Player("Younes", "Kaboul", true),
        new Player("Benoit", "Assou-Ekotto", false),
        new Player("Jan", "Vertonghen", false),
        new Player("Michael", "Dawson", false),
        new Player("William", "Gallas", true),
        new Player("Kyle", "Walker", false),
        new Player("Scott", "Parker", false),
        new Player("Mousa", "Dembele", false),
        new Player("Sandro", "Cordeiro", true),
        new Player("Tom", "Huddlestone", false),
        new Player("Gylfi","Sigurdsson", false),
        new Player("Gareth", "Bale", false),
        new Player("Aaron", "Lennon", false),
        new Player("Jermane", "Defoe", false),
        new Player("Emmanuel", "Adebayor", true)
    );
  data =  FXCollections.<Player>observableArrayList( 
        new Callback<Player, Observable[]>() {
          @Override
          public Observable[] call(Player player) {
            return new Observable[]{player.injuredProperty()};
          }
        }
    );
    data.addAll(players);
    data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Player>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(
          javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Player> change) {
        System.out.println("List changed");
        while (change.next()) {
          if (change.wasUpdated()) {
              System.out.println("What code a do here");
        System.out.println();  }
        }
      }
    });
     table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
                if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
                    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
                    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                    Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
                    System.out.println("Selected Value " + val);
                    System.out.println("Selected row " + newValue);
       }
            }
        });
    return data ;
  }

  public static class Player {
    private final StringProperty firstName ;
    private final StringProperty lastName ;
    private final BooleanProperty injured ;
    Player(String firstName, String lastName, boolean international) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
      this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
      this.injured = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "injured", international);
    }
    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName.set(firstName);}
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName ; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName.set(lastName); }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName ; }    
    public boolean isInjuredl() { return injured.get(); }
    public void setInjured(boolean international) { this.injured.set(international); }
    public BooleanProperty injuredProperty() { return injured ; }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get() + (injured.get()?" (injured)":"");
    }
  }
}
```

it gives me the output like

```
Selected row: Gareth    Bale
```

but it doesn't tell weather Checkbox is selected or not on function:

```
public void onChanged
```

I need an output like:

```
 Selected row: Gareth    Bale   true
```

or

```
 Selected row: Gareth    Bale   false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your if:

```
  if (change.wasUpdated()) {
      String inj = (data.get(change.getFrom()).injured.getValue())?"injuried":"no longer injuried";
      System.out.println(data.get(change.getFrom()).lastName.getValue() + ", " + 
              data.get(change.getFrom()).firstName.getValue() + "  "
              + "changed his status to " + inj);
      System.out.println();  
  }
```

**Note** the output as it is will only display if the player is injuried otherwise it will be blank:

> Selected row: Gareth    Bale   (injured)
>
> Selected row: Gareth    Bale

To replace it to:

> Selected row: Gareth    Bale   true
>
> Selected row: Gareth    Bale   false

**You will also have to change this function in the player class:**

```
public String toString() {
  return firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get() + (injured.get()?" true":" false");
}
```

Comment: one more problem during click function of `Dump info` it gives to complete data by it is not in the format to insert it into mysql database `insert into mysqltable value("all data here with ,data1 ,data2 ,true  this format ");`

Comment: or if you can help me to get the `Dump info` using for loop row by row like: `for(row=0;row<=row.rowcount();row++)` or something like that which will help me to save complete `dump info` into `mysql database`

Comment: This *problem* have nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: what ? i want to know the concept behind dump info and change its output format please help..

Comment: why i have get -2 in my question

Comment: Probably because your question is asking for help on basic subjects and because you are still asking for more help here and most users usually downvote [help-vampires](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Comment: i am asking more questions here because i am blocked to ask new question so please me..