# javafx how to get selected data from tableview using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am working on a project a i want to get the selected data of tableview but i am using FXML.

I have codes for no-FXML but i am unable to use it for FXML.

code:

```
public class person1 {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final StringProperty surname = new SimpleStringProperty("");
 private final StringProperty goodnameof1 = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public person1(String firstName) {
        setFirstName(firstName);

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname.get();
    }

    public void setSurname(String name) {
        surname.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty surnameProperty() {
        return surname;
    }
        public String getGoodnameof1() {
        return goodnameof1.get();
    }

    public void setGoodnameof1(String name) {
        goodnameof1.set(name);
    }


}
```

TestController:

```
public class TestController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    
      @FXML
    private TableView<person1> table;


    @FXML
    void add(ActionEvent event) {


   table.getItems().add(new person1("dsdsd"));
    }


}
```

**now i want to know what i code to get selected data from tableview**

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: My (limited) understanding would suggest that FXML is only a descriptive language which defines the initial state of the UI, it's not an interactive/executable code element.  Perhaps you need to expand on your problem a little more to make it more clear

Comment: You might find the code in this question useful: [get selected row in TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144951/javafx-how-to-get-selected-row-data-in-table-view-with-checkbox/24145872#24145872). Despite of not having the FXML (which is useless for getting the data) it provides you a way to get the data. (look at the code in the question and the answer).

Comment: Link it doesn't contain fxml.

Comment: or you can only help me to get integer selected row index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the selected row index, then use

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```