# CheckBoxTableCell changelistener not working

Tags: java, javafx, listener, tableview, tablecell

I'm trying to add a change listener to my CheckBoxTableCells but it doesn't seem to be working. I took the example for CheckBoxes figuring they would work the same way. However there is no output when i change its value. How would i add one correctly to a checkboxtablecell?

current code:

```
tc.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Trainee, Boolean>, TableCell<Trainee, Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Trainee, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Trainee, Boolean> p) {
                        final CheckBoxTableCell ctCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
                        ctCell.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
                                System.out.println(new_val);
                            }
                        });
                        return ctCell;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I also made my own CheckBoxTableCell and it worked, but because of the functionality requirements i'd rather do it from within the class i'm currently working in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javafx how to get selected row data in table view with checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144951/javafx-how-to-get-selected-row-data-in-table-view-with-checkbox)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `selectedProperty` is inherited from `Cell` and it just indicates whether the `Cell` is selected in the UI component. Since you probably don't have cell selection enabled on your `TableView`, the cell never becomes selected. This isn't what you're looking for anyway; you want to know whether the `CheckBox` is selected, not the `Cell`.

The trick here is to use the `selectedStateCallback` property of the `CheckBoxTableCell`. This is a function that maps the index of the cell to a `BooleanProperty`. That `BooleanProperty` is bound bidirectionally to the selected state of the check box.

If your column is representing an actual property in your `Trainee` class (I'll just call it `selectedProperty` for demonstration) then you can do something like this:

```
final CheckBoxTableCell<Trainee, Boolean> ctCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
ctCell.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer index) {
        return table.getItems().get(index).selectedProperty();
    }
});
```

Then the property in the `Trainee` class with be bidirectionally bound to the check box state. If you need to do more than just update your model object when the check box is selected/deselected, you can just observe that property.

If you don't have a property in the `Trainee` class, you can just create a `BooleanProperty` and observe it:

```
final CheckBoxTableCell<Trainee, Boolean> ctCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
ctCell.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer index) {
        return selected ;
    }
});
selected.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasSelected, Boolean isSelected) {
        System.out.println(isSelected);
    }
});
```

As usual, all this code looks a lot nicer in Java 8.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thanks again! You've helped me out so much today. Need to tweak it for a bit, but i'll manage. I can't thank you enough for how much you've helped me today!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much ... great and simple solution!

Comment: What if I do have a SimpleBooleanProperty field in the Trainee class? Can you share the code for it?