# JavaFX Table View CellValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I've ran into a weird problem which I can't seem to fix. I'm making a table view which one column has a checkbox inside of it.

Although I'm trying to add a change listener to the `CheckBoxTableCell` but not having any luck.

If I do this:

```
            final CheckBoxTableCell<Plugin, Boolean> ctCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
        enabled.setCellFactory(p -> ctCell);
```

The checkbox's do not show up at all on the tableview.

But if I do this:

```
enabled.setCellFactory(p -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
```

The checkboxes show up fine? Why does the second one show the checkboxes but the first one doesn't? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you create an object and pass it multiple times. As per JavaFX scene graph documentation a node can only be attached to a single parent and a parent cannot have duplicate children.

In the second case you create a new object every time to populate the cells. This is what should be done, as the method expects a factory, in other words an object that produces a new object every call.

Comment: How can I add a listener to the second example to detect when the checkbox gets unchecked/checked by a user then?

Comment: You will need to provide another Callback, please refer to documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html

Comment: Your "follow up" question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210690/checkboxtablecell-changelistener-not-working