# JavaFX TreeView buggy behaviour

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created a TreeView with checkbox tree items. I wanted to add listener to each checkbox, so I created a sample problem. But I got some pretty weird behavior. When I click on a checkbox, it actually triggered the handler for both itself and the one above it.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{
  @FXML
  public AnchorPane container;

  public static class CustomTreeCell extends CheckBoxTreeCell<String> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);
      if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
      } else {
        setText(item);
        ((CheckBox) getGraphic()).selectedProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
          System.out.println("Clicked on: " + item);
        }));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
    treeView.setCellFactory((TreeView<String> param) -> new CustomTreeCell());
    container.getChildren().add(treeView);
    CheckBoxTreeItem root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Root");
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    CheckBoxTreeItem leaf_A = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Leaf A");
    CheckBoxTreeItem leaf_B = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Leaf B");
    CheckBoxTreeItem leaf_C = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Leaf C");
    root.getChildren().addAll(leaf_A, leaf_B, leaf_C);
  }
}
```

After running the application, when I click on Leaf B, it prints out this:

Clicked on: Leaf A
Clicked on: Leaf B

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening for days but still couldn't find out why.

Any hints are appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `((CheckBox) getGraphic()).setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Clicked on: " + item));`

rather than listening on selection change.

Answer (score 0):

`updateItem` is called any time the cell is reused to show a different item. This can happen quite often, and the API (deliberately) does not specify exactly when (i.e. it's an implementation detail). Typically, though, it happens frequently if, for example, the user scrolls in the table.

Your `updateItem()` method adds new listeners to the check box every time, and never removes those listeners. So what you might observe is more and more listeners getting fired the more you have scrolled in the table. (Try adding enough items to your table to allow scrolling, scroll around a lot, and then check/uncheck a check box.)

The intended use is to set the [`selectedStateCallBack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html#selectedStateCallbackProperty) to map to a property in your model class. Then if you want to react to changes, you can do so by observing the property in the model. This is explained in [CheckBoxTableCell changelistener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210690/checkboxtablecell-changelistener-not-working).